# Usage of swipe gesture on tableView with image changing

Tags: ios, swift

My query is that I have 10 image in array which is visible on collectionViewCell. When I click on 4th cell, the whole array should move to another controller where I am using FSPagerView to display single image. After that when I swipe left or right, the image should be display according to indexes. I have done this task around 90%, means I have got the image index while left or right swipe but I am not able to set that on image. How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use UIPageViewController,  Only you have to pass Image in array it will Show According to Index.

Comment: thanks @Ravindra Bhati. Let me check.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Can't need to add gesture on an image and all simply you can also do it with collection view.

Comment: But how using the collectionView ?